# Remove "Chapter" from a book text

Tags: chapters

I am finishing my master thesis and I need to remove the "Chapter" name from my chapter without removing the relative number of the chapter. (I am using the `book` class)

What I have now is:

> Chapter 1.
> Name of the chapter.

What I need is:

> 1. Name of the chapter.

I tried with `titlesec`, but the code I had changed the font as well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We prefer a starting document, not just some feature request. Do you really have `Chapter 1. Name of the Chapter` in one line?

Comment: could you possible produce an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for this? It is difficult to know exactly why your code changes your font as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how you can do with `titlesec` (you may be wanting to add some `\titlespacing` instructions).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\thechapter.\ }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Abstract}

abc

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

abc

\end{document}
```

Technical note: the image has been produced with the `oneside` option in order to limit the number of pages

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is a small sample code for the `\chapter` header (not `\chapter*`, however.). The relevant portion is hidden in `\@makechapterhead`.

It's valid only for `Number. Name` without line breaking in between.

```
\documentclass{book}



\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \Huge\bfseries\space\thechapter.\space
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]